# why I can't transfer variables between two view controllers this way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have one view who calculates location and reverser geocode to get the zip code. Then it calls another view where I want to display weather results based on that zip code.

In the first view controller I do this once user clicks on the button to turn the page:

```
- (IBAction) showMyWeather : (id)sender {

WeatherApp *weather = [[WeatherApp alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
weather.zipcode = placemarkZip; //this one seems not to be doing the job
weather.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:weather animated:YES];

}
```

And at the WeatherApp I would like to read now zipcode, which is declared in this view controller .h:

```
@interface WeatherApp : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIButton *done;
MKPlacemark *zipcode;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPlacemark *zipcode;
```

How can I use this code to transfer this zipcode to the WeatherApp? Thanks!

Comment: if you add a breakpoint, is the placemarkZip variable is correct ? What is the value of the zipcode member when you set it ? And don't forget to release weather after presentModalViewController

Comment: how do u know that it's not gonna set? I mean where did u add the break point or nslogged it?

Comment: True - it was not the correct value...placemarkzip was in fact the whole placemark. In general (sorry for deviating from the subject...) - is it ok to pass info to other objects like that? It's confusing cause when entering the WeatherApp object, the zipcode is suddenly there, although it's a general class....(not sure I am making sense...). Thanks again!

Comment: you need to release weather at the end of this method, otherwise it will leak.

Comment: seems okay to me...please check placemarkZip is allocated, i mean not nil...check that by nsloging before passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a fine way to pass information into your new object.

Alternatively, you could create a custom initializer for WeatherApp like

```
- (id)initWithZipCode:(NSString *)zip;
```

and then in the implementation file, it could be like this:

```
- (id)initWithZipCode:(NSString *)zip
{
    self = [super init];
    [self setZipcode:zip];
    return self;
}
```

Finally, you could instantiate the class like so:

```
- (IBAction)showMyWeather:(id)sender
{
    WeatherApp *weather = [[WeatherApp alloc] initWithZipCode:placemarkZip];
    [weather setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:weather animated:YES];
    [weather release]; // No longer needed with ARC... just sayin'
}
```

Finally, if you're going to continue to pass in information as you do above, I'd question why you're using `initWithNibName:bundle:`. If you're just going to pass `nil` to both, why not just use `[[WeatherApp alloc] init]`?